# Vertical align and line-height in css

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

I have two probably easy CSS questions here:
http://web288.merkur.ibone.ch/klingler/

How can I get the `© Klingler Fahrzeugtechnik AG 2013` in the footer vertically aligned to the bottom? I tried `align-bottom` and vertical align of the p tag but without luck...

The second thing is, I feal the distance between the lines of the main text is a bit narrow. I wanted to have a bigger line height. I tried changing the line-height property of the p tag to 2.5em instead of 1.5em but this did not change anything? Why is this?

```
p {
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Your live site suggests the line-height is defined twice (once in typography.css line 158 and then overwritten in screen-PAGE-layout.css line 88)

Comment: Too bad, I am sorry for this stupid question. I was looking for a second definition but could not find it... What about the alignment thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
footer {
    position: relative;
}

.ym-g25 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
.ym-g25 {
width: 25%;
vertical-align: bottom;
display: table-cell;
line-height: 1;
float: none;
}
```

Comment: What is the line-height and width for here?